# How to use SUM IF() in MySQL without hard coding values in the query

Tags: mysql

I have a query that uses SUM IF() to do a cross-tab result set.  In this query I have the value sin the SUM IF() hard coded.  The problem is that new values are added to the database.  Is there a way to write the query without hard coding the values in the SUM IF()?  Here is the query:

> select storeid, sum(if(marketsegmentid = 6, 1, 0)) as `6`,
>   sum(if(marketsegmentid = 7, 1, 0))
>       as `7`, sum(if(marketsegmentid = 12, 1, 0)) as `12`, sum(if(marketsegmentid = 17, 1, 0)) as `17`,
>       sum(if(marketsegmentid = 22, 1, 0)) as `22`, sum(if(marketsegmentid = 27, 1, 0)) as `27`,
>       sum(if(marketsegmentid = 32, 1, 0)) as `32`, sum(if(marketsegmentid = 37, 1, 0)) as `37`,
>       sum(if(marketsegmentid = 42, 1, 0)) as `42`, sum(if(marketsegmentid = 47, 1, 0)) as `47`,
>       sum(if(marketsegmentid = 52, 1, 0)) as `52`, sum(if(marketsegmentid = 97, 1, 0)) as `97`,
>       sum(if(marketsegmentid = 102, 1, 0)) as `102`, sum(if(marketsegmentid = 107, 1, 0)) as `107`,
>       sum(if(marketsegmentid = 112, 1, 0)) as `112`, sum(if(marketsegmentid = 117, 1, 0)) as `117`,
>       sum(if(marketsegmentid = 122, 1, 0)) as `122`, sum(if(marketsegmentid = 127, 1, 0)) as `127`,
>       sum(if(marketsegmentid = 132, 1, 0)) as `132`, sum(if(marketsegmentid = 137, 1, 0)) as `137`,
>       sum(if(marketsegmentid = 142, 1, 0)) as `142`
>       from storemarketsegments
>       group by storeid;

The query is used in a report and the results are exported to CSV.  The 1's are used as flags in the result set.

The table I am querying is set up like this:

```
CREATE TABLE storemarketsegments(id INT NOT NULL, marketsegmentid INT NOT NULL);
```

The marketsegments are kept in a separate table:

> CREATE TABLE marketsegment(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY
>   KEY(id), name VARCHAR(45), description VARCHAR(45));

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am not sure if there is a way to write the query without hard coding the values and I don't mind updating the query in the report whenever new marketsegments are added but thought I would check.  Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return each count as a separate row, and then filter as needed in the application layer:

```
select storeid, marketsegmentid, count(*) as Count
from storemarketsegments 
group by storeid, marketsegmentid;
```

Comment: This worked.  Thank you for your help.  +1 ( I can't up vote anything yet).